# Lost dual displays in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, unity, xorg, multiple-monitors

After upgrade i cant connect two displays to my Dell Latitude e6430. Everything was fine until today, when i came to work and turned on my PC connected to two samsung displays resolution on them went crazy.

Can't set up 1980x1080 on both screens simultaneously cause one screen is getting too wide and other have some small resolution that cant be used.

Any ideas?

```
ple@ple-Latitude:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor 
Graphics  Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] (rev a1)
```

---

Thanks for replies! :)

I can set up the displays on both monitors. But the thing is now:

When i put the screens in configuration in proper order (left and right as it is in real) then display is extended (for ex. browser) on both monitors and i cant simply maximize window on one of them (it is maximized on both screens). When i switch places in configuration (left with right) then it is displaying good but i have to move my pointer in opposite direction to move windows on second monitor.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: The reason for this not working in Dual-graphics setup is that Dell decided not to connect the digital output connectors with the integrated Intel graphics. Digital output only work in Nvidia GPU-mode only (Optimus disabled). Optimus still works, but just as in any other OS, HDMI/DVI & DisplayPort will not work with Optimus enabled (confirmed on E6230+E6530). Before upgrading Ubuntu, I think Optimus was disabled, explaining why it worked before. Ubuntu 14.04 supports Optimus out of the box ('Nvidia prime' is the search keyword here), breaking the digital video outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Simply disaple Optimus option in BIOS (Video -> optimus). This is only supported in Win7 and Win8.

http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a video drive issue. Are you connecting the displays to the onboard Intel video controller or the NVIDIA controller?

If you are using the NVIDIA controller, I'd recommend going to the NVIDIA site, looking up the NVS5200M video controller, downloading the driver for Linux, and then reload the driver and reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go to the NVidia site to download their driver, as you'll never get rid of it in the future.

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.